# Why Php variable repeats 1 entry?

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, php, entry

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="1937" variable_prefix="items_"}
    $titlu_carte = '{items_title} ';       
    $gestiune_id = '{product_sku} ';
    $cantitate_carte = '{items_quantity}';
   $pret_numeric_carte = '{items_price_numeric}';           
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}

echo $titlu_carte;
echo $gestiune_id;
echo $cantitate_carte;
echo $pret_numeric_carte;
```

Result:

```
TITLE1 012L000001 2 12 TITLE1 ( again ? why not the next title? ) 2 12
```

Why is it giving me the same book and not the next one in the entry?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be good practice to output data with PHP while you can do the same with tags. In your code, you are outputting the PHP variables out of `{exp:cartthrob:order_items}` which is looping. PHP variables within the paired tag loop will store only the last tag values which will be outputted.

So either prepare your PHP variable (within) loop by concatenating or output within the loop.

Comment: I got solved wilth multidimensional arrays in Php